# Minimum amount of negative energy required in warp drive spacetimes

Tags: general-relativity, warp-drives, exotic-matter

In the [pioneering work](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0009013v1) of Alcubierre, to power a warp drive-like geometry it is necessary to employ an amount of negative energy larger (in absolute value) than the whole observable universe mass.
A [later refinement](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9905084v5) by Den Broeck brings the requirements down to a few solar masses.

What is the current minimum amount of negative energy required to build a warp drive-like spacetime? (with link to the reference please)

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcubierre_drive#Mass%E2%80%93energy_requirement) discusses the various exotic mass requirements. A common figure given these days is around Jupiter's mass.

Comment: @PM2Ring Are there any compelling reasons to think that *any* exotic mass suitable for an Alcubierre drive could be created, or is it just wishful thinking that such a thing could exist? If it is just wishful thinking, then I will vote to close this question as non-mainstream physics.

Comment: @G.Smith Personally, I'm *extremely* sceptical that negative mass exotic matter can exist. But there are quite a few unclosed questions in the warp-drive & exotic-matter tags, so I guess it's considered borderline, rather than definitely non-mainstream.

Comment: @G.Smith: *Are there any compelling reasons to think that any exotic mass suitable for an Alcubierre drive could be created, or is it just wishful thinking that such a thing could exist?* There isn't a simple answer to your question. Relativists don't really talk about negative energy, they talk about energy conditions, and there are a bunch of different energy conditions. We pretty much know that none of the energy conditions are universally valid, but we also expect them to hold in bulk matter. A nice summary is Barcelo and Visser, http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0205066

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks for your link, but I'm not able to locate the details of the calculations yet.

Comment: @G.Smith Negative energy is allowed in Quantum Field Theory, very famously in the Casimir effect.

Comment: Not sure who closed the question, but do you understand that we are talking about general relativity here? Since this is the current widely accepted theory of gravitation, this cannot be off-topic. The question explicitly mentioned published papers, the first answer too, and the second show a recent paper with a calculation inside general relativity. There is no personal theory or similar here.

Answer (score 0):

According to this paper by Krasnikov, the energy requirement can be brought down to approximately $10^{-3} g$ for a human-usable warp drive:

[The quantum inequalities do not forbid spacetime shortcuts](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0207057)

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer to this after some time: [Hyperwave: Hyper-Fast Communication within General Relativity](https://arxiv.org/abs/2311.12069)

For Planckian warp space-times the negative energy can be as low as $10^8 J$, less (in absolute magnitude) than the energy contained in an average lighting bolt or in about 10kg of crude oil. The caveat is that being so small it cannot be used for interstellar travel, so not really a traditional warp drive.